# Empty File Content Which Used by Another Process

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

I have a log file of my application, I do some manipulation by sided application on the log file.
 At the end of the manipulation, I want to delete the file - which is not possible becuase file is used, so I just want to empty it - delete the contents.

I tried:

```
 using (FileStream stream = File.Open(query.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, true))
            {
                writer.Write("");
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

and:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(query.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.SetLength(0);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

and:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path", string.Empty);
```

Notihg works.

How to overrride file content?

Answer (score 2):

> Not at all. It will crash, because file is being used by another process

Well, it probably isn't another process, it probably is yours.  You'll have to do this after closing the log file.  But there's a more general fix for that.  Go back to the code that creates the log file and add the FileShare.Delete option.

This option allows deleting files that are in use.  You can now simply use File.Delete() in your code, even if the log file is still opened.  This will put the file in a "delete pending" state, anybody that tries to open it will be slapped with an access denied error.  The file on the disk will automatically disappear when the last handle to the file is closed.

Yet another useful option is FileOptions.DeleteOnClose.  Now it is completely automatic, the file is automatically deleted without you having to do anything at all.  I can't tell which one is best in your case, you probably want to avoid deleting the log file when your program crashed so FileShare.Delete is best.

Comment: I can not change the file creation. It was created by EnterpriceLibrary and would be released only when the application finished work.The idea is to remove the log files from the client into the server at night, I have to delete the file immediately after copied to the server, in order not to be copied twice.

Comment: Obviously this will be hard to fix if you can't change anything.  A sane approach would be to just not copy the log file.

Comment: I can change and I have to do it. but this is a new question, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code too

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Path of your file",string.Empty);
```

Comment: Not at all. It will crash, because file is being used by another process